# How to combine multiple filters in javascript or lodash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So am creating a filter screen React Native, when user clicks apply filter we will be getting a array

```
Input Array

type = ["A/C", "Seater", "Sleeper"];
```

Some time i will be getting only one from the above, in that case i can easily use filter from lodash to run the filter function. But if i get array like above how to implement this with filter ?

As user can wish to filter the list using A/C alone or sometimes A/C and Seater, when we get more than one selection how to implement this on filter ?

```
trying with switch

filterHandler(depature, busType)
    {   
         switch (depature) {
             case type:
                 this.setState({ availableList: this.state.List.filter(o => o.AC === "true")});
             default:
                 return;
         }
    }
```

As, if i use switch case for each then my switch case will be very huge, is there any professional way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to filter some array using another array. You could do it like this:

```
const filteredArray = arrayToFilter.filter(item=>type.every(t=>item[t]))
```